# Make many dynamic variable (inctance name) with one loop

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, variables

I have many class in my library almost 300, and I want to generate instance name by loop. In other words I wanna instead of this approach(witch has many code line):

`X:`This is my problem:

```
var cm1: Cm1 = new Cm1();
var cm2: Cm2 = new Cm2();
var cm3: Cm3 = new Cm3();
...
```

use like this approach (less than 10 code lines):

`Y:`I think this is solution:

```
for (var i: uint = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    var getChildByName("cm" + i): getChildByName("Cm" + i) = new getChildByName("Cm" + i);
}
```

but I know above code does not work, is there any way to make them !

-What am I actually trying to solve?

Make many variable by a few line code and save time and size app!

-Why do I have ~300 classes and why are you trying to create them in a loop at once?

This is about to data of request application!

-What do these classes do that you unconditionally need one of each all at the same time?

Because those data would show at first time!

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve? Why do you have ~300 classes and why are you trying to create them in a loop at once? What do these classes do that you unconditionally need one of each all at the same time?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you're trying to say. Can you edit your question with details of what you're trying to do? What you have now is likely an X - Y problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Edited that for clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is better to store the classes in an Array or Object rather than an external variable for each item. if you want to access them by name, better to use object:

```
var classList:Object=new Object();
```

Then in your loop:

```
for(var i:uint=1;i<NumberOfClasses;i++){
    classList["cm"+i.toString()]=new (getDefinitionByName("Cm"+i.toString()) as Class)();
}
```

`getDefinitionByName` is used to make Constructors using String;

> Note: if your classes contain a package directory, you should include it.  for example:

```
getDefinitionByName("myclasses.cm.Cm123")();
```

Then you can access them using **Bracket syntax**:

```
classList["cm123"].prop=val;
```

And don't forget to:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
```

I Hope it will help.

**EDIT**

to use Array instead of object, the loop should be:

```
for(var i:uint=1;i<NumberOfClasses;i++){
    classList[i]=new (getDefinitionByName("Cm"+i.toString()) as Class)();
}
```

then to access them:

```
addChild(classList[0]);//0 or any other index;
```

Comment: because I used object to access them using name. so you should use `addChild(classList["cm1"]);` for example. not using numbers.

Comment: Merci, I wanna to make variable e.g. `cm1` and `cm2` and `...` until `addChild(classList[0])`works and this too :`addChild(cm1)`, can I?

Comment: well I don't really understand why you still have problem, and you can't create variables using this loop. if you want variables, you should create them all manually and without loop. the only ways are using object and using array.

Comment: Can u solve it:`for (var i: uint = 1; i < 2; i++)
   {
    g[i - 1] = new(getDefinitionByName("group" + i.toString()) as RadioButtonGroup)("");
   }` for make many group of RadioButtonGroup, thx.

Comment: I don't know much about working with radiobuttons. what's your problem in that code?